# Parse an email message to readable form Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

Thanks to several users on here, I now am able to connect to the server via IMAP and download all of the unread messages. The problem, however, is that themessages are not in a readable form. Do I need to figure out a way to render the HTML in my application?

**Here is my code:**

```
import imaplib

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
server.login('USER', 'PASS')

server.select('INBOX')

resp, items = server.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")

for mail in items[0].split():
    resp, data = server.fetch(mail, '(RFC822)')
    body = data[0][1]
    print body
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real password.

Comment: change it _really fast_. This is a public website.

Comment: @Gabi, It's already been changed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module. It can help you extract the data you want from the message body.